# How to set UITabBarItem.badgevalue when i use storyboard to show multi view?

Tags: storyboard, uitabbaritem

I chose "tabbed Application" to create one project which has four tabbaritems. And also, i choose "using storyboard". Now, i have one question, how can i show the badge value on tabbaritem if i reload data in the tableview. Any suggestions? Thanks.